# Microsoft eshop on containers micro-service event subscription pattern

Tags: docker, .net-core, microservices

With regards to the Microsoft eshop on containers example code hosted here:

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

The micro-services in the application use a pattern whereby they subscribe to events on startup in their Startup.cs file e.g.

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Payment/Payment.API/Startup.cs

```
private void RegisterEventBus(IServiceCollection services)
```

Does this work in a hosted environment e.g. Azure? Wouldn't a side-effect of this be that the services could be shutdown due to inactivity and remain dormant until a request (HTTP) arrives where the app would start and events would suddenly begin to be processed? Or is the fact that these are intended to be deployed in containers what makes this stable i.e. will they always be running?

Comment: From what I see, there is a configuration enabled for Azure: `if (Configuration.GetValue<bool>("AzureServiceBusEnabled"))` so it should work.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Yes, indeed it is designed to run on Azure, I'm really just questioning the pattern of setting up the subscriptions in the app startup.